# Windows7 issue in mutli- tasking and memory

Tags: windows-7, memory, bios, memory-management, multitasking

I seeming some problem in my windows OS recently, let me first say my system configuration.
processor - Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU Q8400 @ 2.66 GHz
Installed memory (RAM) - 4.00 GB (3.00 GB usable)
System type - 32 bit operating system

I am using two OS in this system, first one is Windows7 and the other is centOS. Well, I am using this from a long time there was no problem , and all of a sudden since from couple weeks I am facing problems in my Windows7 OS. 
In windows7 i was nearing using multiple jobs almost every time i log in, there was no problem but now i don't no what happen I am not able to do multiple jobs at same time.
For example-
1> I am now not able to listen to music in windows media player and view photo's. All of a sudden the system stops working and does not respond and then respond after 5mins and the music get played where it got stopped after 5 mins.
2> When i start browersing internet it hangs all of sudden and doesn't respond for 2 or 3 mins and gets loading. 
I mean it just happens for every operation i do in the system. Even now typing was also difficult, it gets hanged very frequently even though i am doing single task. I have never come across this kind of problem before.
So the first thing i did was to see the useage of the processor and the memory. Well, i thick the useage of the processor was fine, for single task the useage was some where around 3 to 5%. 
Well, it was something weird i found in the memory, in spite of no task that i was running it was using somewhere around 34 to 41% of memory. So i opened the task manager and click on resource monitor in performance tab. And in the memory section of the monitoring tool i found the usage of my RAM, it was something like this.
Hardware reserved - 1029 MB
In Use - 1430 MB
Modified - 49 MB
Standby - 1566 MB
free - 22 MB

And i could also see

Available 1588 MB 
Cached 1615 MB
Total 3067 MB
Installed 4096 MB

well, this if all i could find out and i have no idea why my computer is acting so weird all of a sudden and the performance problem is growing day by day and i also don't know if there is problem in Bios, i have let it for default settings from long time. 
please help me and Thank you in advance for reading this and helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to make sure the CPU isn't overheating. That's not that likely because usually when the CPU is overheating, the CPU usage is high. But it's still worth checking. Make sure the fan spins and the heat sink is properly attached. Clean out dust.

Sweep for malware. You can use MalwareBytes AntiMalware.

Your memory usage all seems normal.

Comment: Thank you for replying.
After you said i checked the CPU temperature in the BIOS settings -> the hardware monitoring tool, it has 

Processor Thermal Margin : -1C , 
Motherboard Temperature : 45C, 
+12v : 12.032 V ,
+5v : 5.056 V , 
+3.3V : 3.152 V ,
5v standby : 4.928 V,
Processor voltage : 1.096 V,
CPU cooling FAN : 3245 RPM ,
Rear chassis FAN : N/A,
And i also use McAfee Antivirus plus